# Legal to hire a model for non-professional pictures under ESTA/VWP?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, work

I recently started to practice a lot my photography skills and I would like to further improve them. I'll be traveling to the US under ESTA and staying in a nice hotel. I'd love to hire a model from an agency, but I suspect that even if I'm not getting any income, and NOT working for anyone, that it qualifies for work and it is thus illegal.

Does it change if I do not get any rights for the pictures?

Comment: Your admission to the US is governed by the terms of the Visa Waiver Program.  ESTA is a travel authorization; if you want information about your status after you've traveled using ESTA, you might fare better if you search for "VWP" instead of "ESTA".

Comment: You do get copyright for the pictures, it's automatic.

Comment: Be aware that many models are willing to work for 'free' on the basis that the resulting shots are not for commercial use, but go into both their and your portfolio. This could be a great way to avoid your visa issues *and* save money - assuming the 'no-commercial-use' agreement is good for you. You need to have some experience though, or at least find a model on the same level of experience and 'fame' as you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be amateur/hobby/pleasure (no income) for which only a B2 visa would be needed. B2 is one of the categories covered under the VWP.

The more important question will be how to convince immigration that you are not intending to sell those photo's afterwards. Immigration does not work on a presumption of innocence. Signing up for a photography course (not as part of a format study program) might help show your amateur status, yet is compatible with B2/VWP.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it is pretty clear. I guess that even planning to publish them in a book in the future still would qualify as work, but I guess we are moving from vwp questions to something a little off-topic.

Comment: Would be good to add some references here. Consider https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html and https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf